# Fitting two parameter observations into copulas

Tags: r, data-fitting

I have one set of observations containing two parameters.

How to fit it into copula (estimate the parameter of the copula and the margin function)?

Let's say the margin distribution are log-normal distributions, and the copula is Gumbel copula.

The data is as below:

```
1   974.0304 1010
2  6094.2672 1150
3  3103.2720 1490
4  1746.1872 1210
5  6683.7744 3060
6  6299.6832 3330
7  4784.0112 1550
8  1472.4288  607
9  3758.5728 1970
10 4381.2144 1350

Library(copula)
gumbel.cop <- gumbelCopula(dim=2)
myMvd <- mvdc(gumbel.cop, c("lnorm","lnorm"), list(list(meanlog = 7.1445391,sdlog=0.4568783), list(meanlog = 7.957392,sdlog=0.559831)))
x <- rmvdc(myMvd, 1000)
fit <- fitMvdc(x, myMvd, c(7.1445391,0.4568783,7.957392,0.559831))
```

The `meanlog` and `sdlog` value are derived from the data set. Error message:

```
"Error in if (alpha - 1 < .Machine$double.eps^(1/3)) return(rCopula(n,  : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"
```

How to choose the copula parameter with the given data, and the margin distributions derived from the data set?

Comment: What did you try? Which problems do you face?

Comment: thank you very much for reply. I have finished the univariate analysis for both parameter, estimated the distribution fitted the "log-normal" distribution. And I install the "copula" package, the function "fitCopula" required a parameter for the copula, I didn't quite understand, because this is the one which I am going to estimate. Also, how to convert the distribution (log-normal) to uniform marginal distribution for copula analysis?

Comment: If you have more question related to this one edit the question and add it. So when you use this function without this parameter what is the exact error? Could you copy it? Did you read the help of the package about this parameter? Could you short the data showed (just 5 lines or 10 will do) and copy the code you use to analyse it? This way we can directly copy and paste your code to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the questions a little bit :)

Comment: The data you show is in the `gumbleCopula` object? 
When do you get this error after running fitMvdc? It says that need a parameter TRUE or FALSE, so in the help menu whatever functions raises this error should explain what does this. But you can try adding a new parameter=TRUE and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Llopis! i modified the code a lit bit, and got the pseudo obeservation probability first, then the fitting function works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question assessed in the comments.
It seems that giving a parameter of TRUE or FALSE close the problem as well as doing first the pseudo-observation and then fit the function.